# ASK // Script Hooks push another repository

Tags: php, git, gitlab, githooks, phabricator

I am trying to do the automatic deployment script [using git hooks](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa) and it is working, but only for copying a repository.

What I want to do is to automatically push to place another repository such as github/gitlab. How do I configure the script hooks in order to push it to where the other repository is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using phabricator, you can define mirrors in diffusion. Therefore add a new URI like this:

[image]

Phabricator now syncs all repository actions to the mirror sites.

Comment: If I add a URI, whether while doing push-ups will do also push to the uri that was just added?

Comment: If I get your question right: Yes Phabricator tries to push every commit to the given mirror sites given by there URIs with I/O type: `Mirror:Push a copy to a remote`

Comment: Is there any additional setting beside as shown on your screenshot?

Comment: You can set credentials afterwards. But that's it basically....
But you can add and remote the URIs for mirros anytime not only within the creation workflow.

Comment: Sure! - But why using both? :D

Comment: i need to do ci/cd on gitlab, im not sure phabricator can do it easily.